# Dell D620 Windows 7 Blank screen

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display

When I installed Windows 7 on my Dell D620 it was all fine until a couple of days later most times when I either shut down or suspend (by closing the lid).  When I unsuspend or startup the computer, there is often a completely blank screen (can't see post screen or anything), and restarting doesn't help.

I've found that I can eventually bring it back up again by suspending and unsuspending a few times, but obviously this is not ideal.

Has anyone else experienced this?  I think it is a driver issue, that somehow the driver is putting the video card into a certain mode that it forgets how to get it back out of.

Any ideas on a better solution than my switching off and on business?

**Edit:** Turns out that the video card had burned out! IT managed to get me a new mainboard sorted for me.

Comment: Which build of Win7 are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Update your graphics driver. Also contact dell and go into power options and change what closing the lid does.Hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would try is try to search for a updated driver for WIN 7. Next, I would reduce the resolution all the way down (when you can see what youre doing) and then test the system to see if it is stable. Win 7 may be asking for a resolution that your laptop can not produce. One other thing to check is to remove the keyboard and check if the monitor output cable has a loose connection to the motherboard. The connecter is very delicate on that model computer.

[Keyboard Removal](http://www.solano.edu/tech_learn_resources/techtips/d620/parts.htm#wp1105803)

The video ribbon cable has a blue tag on it.